# Why am I unable use GET to send parameters to WebMethod?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, getmethod

My WebMethod looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet=true)]
public List<Person> HelloWorld(string hello)
{
   List<Person> persons = new List<Person> 
   {
      new Person("Sarfaraz", DateTime.Now),
      new Person("Nawaz", DateTime.Now),
      new Person("Manas", DateTime.Now)
   };
   return persons;
}
```

And I'm trying to call this method using jQuery as:

```
var params={hello:"sarfaraz"}; //params to be passed to the WebMethod
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",   //have to use GET method
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost:51519/CommentProviderService.asmx/HelloWorld",
    processData: true,
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError      //it gets called!
});
```

But it doesn't work. Instead of calling `onSuccess` callback, it calls `onError` in which I use `alert` as:

```
alert(response.status + " | " + response.statusText + " | " + response.responseText + " | " + response.responseXML );
```

which prints this:

> 500 | Internal Server Error | **{"Message":"Invalid web service call,
>   missing value for parameter: \u0027hello\u0027."**,"StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"} |
>   undefined

I don't understand why I get this error.

If I change the jQuery call to use `POST` method and make `UseHttpGet=false` , then it works great. But I want it to work with `GET`. What needs to be fixed?

Comment: try .asmx/HelloWorld?hello=sarfaraz

Answer (score 1):

HTTP GET expects the parameters to all be encoded in the URL.

The problem is that you are doing a [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on your payload. [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is really just looking for simple dictionary that it can turn into a series of Query String params.

So if you have an object like this:

```
{ name: "value" }
```

jQuery will append it to the end of your URL like this:

```
?name=value
```

Use Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, or IE Developer tools to inspect the outgoing URL and I suspect you will see it is in a format that ASP.Net cannot translate.

Comment: Now, I tried with `{ hello : "sarfaraz" }`, and I get this error : `500 | Internal Server Error | {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: sarfaraz.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()....`

Comment: @Nawaz - Try changing your data param to look like this: `data: {"hello":"sarfaraz"}`

Comment: Ok, it's been a little while since I did this with ASP.Net but I vaguely remember having to completely enclose my data in quotes. So you have one of two things you can try. 1.) `data: "{'hello':'sarfaraz'}"` 2.) stick the data in the URL as query string parameters and use `jQuery.get()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To make an $.ajax request in GET, you will have to set your data as `params="hello=sarfaraz"`

So the complete code snippet can simply be

```
var params="hello=sarfaraz"; //params to be passed to the WebMethod
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",   //have to use GET method
    cache: false,
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost:51519/CommentProviderService.asmx/HelloWorld",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError    //it gets called!
});
```

Hope that helps!